# jquery mobile redirect to div of particular page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I' m using jquery mobile.Now i'm having problem to redirect to the particular div of the page.
the html of the page is

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

<a href='#nav-panel' data-theme="b" data-role='button'>List</a>
<div id="element1"></div>
<div id="element2"></div>
<div id="element3"></div>
</div>
<div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-theme="a" id="nav-panel">
     <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" class="nav-search">             
      <li><a href="#"  id="reload"> element1</a></li>            
        <li><a href="#"  id="reload"> element2</a></li>        
       <li><a href="#"  id="reload"> element3</a></li>                    
       </ul>            
  </div>
```

Initially  element1 is shown. click the panel list and i want to display only element2 and hide other page.
I use redirect like

```
$.mobile.changePage( $("#page1 #element2"));
```

but not working.
Any suggestion will be great.
Thanks

Comment: use `.silentScroll` on `pageshow`. It won't work with `.mobile.changePage`.

Comment: can u show me the code

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/89fyf/

Comment: @Omar i'm using panel that has list and clicking to list show particular element div. so not working

Comment: then on `pageshow`, open the panel and `silentScroll` to it. Can you show more code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33266/discussion-between-anonmous-change-and-omar)